# MySQL query selecting the last date needed but with a different column value that not related to that date at all

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlfiddle

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
t1.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, 'k') USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
min(t3.date_of_visit) as date_of_visit, 
t2.diagnosis_name,
max(ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(t5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result,
(SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (period_diff(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM now()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_of_assessment))>=6) 
    THEN 
        'Yes' 
    ELSE 
        'No'  
    END 
FROM 
    diabetes_assessment t5 
    where t5.patient_id = t1.patient_id LIMIT 1) as assessment_needed
FROM 
    consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 
    ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3 
    ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4 
    ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 
    ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name 
    LIKE '%Diabetes%' 
    AND 
    t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND 
    t3.visit_status='Active'
GROUP BY 
    t1.patient_id
ORDER BY 
    t5.date_of_assessment DESC
```

Where I need to select different columns, and the most ones are the `date_of_assessment`, `assessment_result` and the `case` result.

Here is [an SQL Fiddle about it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0539ec/16).

The problem with the result of those 3 important fields. As you see in this row:

```
|   361-9001 |          (null) |    2017-03-03 | Diabetes mellitus with diabetic nephropathy |         2017-05-05 |                31 |                No |
```

The date selected is the last assessment date done for the patient, but the result of assessment at that specific date is 40 and 31. So The query is returning the right fields but it is just selecting the last date with an arbitrary assessment result that is not related to that date.

Here is the data of assessment table:

```
insert into diabetes_assessment values (1, '361-9001', 361, '2017-04-04', 31);
insert into diabetes_assessment values (2, '361-9001', 361, '2017-05-05', 40);
insert into diabetes_assessment values (3, '361-0361', 361, '2017-03-10', 30.5);
```

So the result should be taken from this line:

insert into diabetes_assessment values (2, '361-9001', 361, '2017-05-05', 40);

I tried to add `max()` to assessment_result but it still giving erroneous not connected data.

Comment: This query is too massive, with many tables, for me to attempt an answer, but I will tell your problem is this: `GROUP BY t1.patient_id` ... you are aggregating over only this column, but then selecting other columns.  Ask yourself _which_ record for each patient will be selected?  Can't' figure it out, well neither can MySQL reliably, which is why you seem to be getting random stuff.

Comment: So I should group by `date_of_assessment` too ?

Comment: I'm not sure...typically you would either aggregate over the other fields, using `MAX()`, or something similar, or in a subquery.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are using mysql  or sql-server  ?????

Comment: Actually I am testing on both. This query from MySQL. I am taking classes on both actually

Comment: That query won't run on both MySQL and SQL Server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql 
If you want values for not aggregated  column you  should match yourquesry with the result fo aggreated  result eg in subquery 
(if you use sql-server instead of tupr match you could use a inner join on the same subselet )

**EDIT: Adding missing parenthesis**

```
SELECT 
t1.patient_id,
CONVERT(aes_decrypt(t4.patient_name_en, 'k') USING utf8mb4) as patient_name_en,
t3.date_of_visit as date_of_visit, 
t2.diagnosis_name,
ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A') as date_of_assessment,
ifnull(t5.assessment_result, 0) as assessment_result,
(
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            (period_diff(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM now()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_of_assessment))>=6) 
        THEN 
            'Yes' 
        ELSE 
            'No'  
        END 
    FROM diabetes_assessment t5 
    where t5.patient_id = t1.patient_id LIMIT 1
) as assessment_needed
FROM consultation t1
LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
LEFT JOIN visit t3  ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
LEFT JOIN patient t4  ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5  ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
WHERE t2.diagnosis_name   LIKE '%Diabetes%' 
AND  t1.clinic_id = '361'
AND  t3.visit_status='Active'
AND ( t1.patient_id,t3.date_of_visit, ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) IN (
    SELECT 
    t1.patient_id,
    min(t3.date_of_visit) as date_of_visit, 
    max(ifnull(t5.date_of_assessment, 'N/A')) as date_of_assessment
    FROM 
        consultation t1
    LEFT JOIN diagnosis t2 
        ON t1.diagnosis_id = t2.diagnosis_id
    LEFT JOIN visit t3 
        ON t3.visit_id = t1.visit_id
    LEFT JOIN patient t4 
        ON t4.patient_id = t3.patient_id
    LEFT JOIN diabetes_assessment t5 
        ON t5.patient_id = t4.patient_id
    WHERE t2.diagnosis_name    LIKE '%Diabetes%' 
    AND  t1.clinic_id = '361'
    AND t3.visit_status='Active'
    GROUP BY t1.patient_id
    ORDER BY t5.date_of_assessment DESC


)
ORDER BY  t5.date_of_assessment DESC
```

NB using left join on tables and where condition on the same tables work as  an INNER JOIN

Comment: Can you explain more about the difference between your query and mine ? Your query actually works now, but can't understand it

Comment: In your query you mix aggregated (min, max) and not aggregated  columns  so you have in not aggregated columns casual results ... In mine .. I  select from the not aggregated  rows the values for the rows  that match with the resut on only the columns with aggregated result  .. so you have not casual values ..for different columns but the the content of the same row. Hope my explanatio is clear .

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I will study your query as well to learn from it

Comment: Just a suggestion be careful for mixing left join and where condition ..

Comment: Can you tell me why ? I have mixed lots of them in my current project

Comment: because   colums related  to  table with left join condition  used in where clause (of the same main select) are equivalent to generate a INNER JOIN result

Comment: Ohhh. I get it. Your answers and comments need more than one thumb up

Comment: Many  thanks  .. if you need  (and you have the time )    .. you can find useful  suggetiion   in my answer  collection  ..

Comment: I need them and I will find the time for them. Usually people annoy me because of my questions but I am willing to learn. Thanks.

Comment: @droidnation 'LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...' is the same as 'INNER JOIN x...'. To see this fact in action, simply run EXPLAIN EXTENDED; followed by SHOW WARNINGS; on a given query